# Auto refresh a page based on user's selected timer interval

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload, intervals

I've tried googling this and I cant seem to find a solution/script.

I want users to be able to be able to choose how often a page reloads.

For example...
The website is split into two iframes.
The top iframe allows the user to enter/select "page will reload every __ seconds".
The bottom iframe is the actual website and it will reload according to the interval set by the user.

p.s. I am familiar with HTML but new to javascript

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would you want to refresh a page at a specified interval? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am using jQuery and javascript in order to auto update the page. Inside the `update()` function I am using AJAX which is able to send a receive data from a URL and then you can output that data using the var `xmlhttp.responseText`

```
var time = //what the user has selected for when the update should happen
setInterval(function() {
    update();
}, time);
function update() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=
        function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                if(xmlhttp.responseText != $('body').val()) {
                    $('body').html(xmlhttp.responseText).fadeIn(500);
                }
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","your_url_to_get_the_updated_page.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```